# Get subplot number from Ginput

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Consider the following example

```
f = figure(1);
ax(1)  = subplot(2,1,1);
plot(1:100,randi(50,1,100));
ax(2)  = subplot(2,1,2);
plot(1:100,randi(50,1,100))
[x,  ~] = ginput(2);  
clickedAx = gca
```

Is there anyway I can the subplot number on which i clicked for ginput from the axes handle properties ? or some other way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `gca` to give you the axes that was clicked and compare this to your array of `axes` using `ismember`.

```
[~, axnum] = ismember(gca, ax);
```

If you don't like specifying two output arguments you could also write

```
axnum = find(ismember(ax, gca));
```

Comment: what if user clicks both axes?